# Handle data security from a central point (Controller Core)?

Tags: php

I have a Controller_Core class which is doing nothing at the moment, but when I want to centralize some general code I can put it there.

I'm wondering if it is possible to work the other way around when one has a class which extends from the Controller_Core. Let's say a typical User has a Controller_User class. In that class I would like to automate adding slashes to the provided parameters from each function in that class. Is this possible without declaring a function `foo` in Controller_Core which does something like `mysql_real_escape_string`?

In other words, is it possible to auto-mysql-real-escape parameters from a method in a(ny) class?

Used language is PHP.

-Update

Lets assume I have this code:

```
class Controller_User extends Controller_Core
{
  public function Login($sUsername, $sPassword)
  {
    # the add-slashes action should be done automatically at this point without calling a specific for such functionality (thus; $sUsername and $sPassword should be 'add-slashed' from RunFromEachCalledExtendedFunction)
    $bValidationResult = // some further code
    return $bValidationResult;
  }
}

class Controller_Core 
{
  public function RunFromEachCalledExtendedFunction
  {
    # some code to determine which method was called, then add-slash those parameters
  }
}

$oControllerUser = new Controller_User();
$bLoginResult = $oControllerUser->Login("my username' OR 1=1", "my pwd");
```

Comment: Possible: Yes.  Should you do that?  *Hell no*.  Please stop using the decrepit mysql extension.  If you're writing OO code, you should be using a modern database library.  Try PDO or mysqli.

Comment: Or any equivalent function to do such things. Then; how can I accomplish to auto-call the Controller_Core from any extended method without auto-calling `$this->MethodName()`

Comment: Can you post some example code, please?  What you have and what you want it to be able to do?  I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Putting them in the first-post/question now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't escape the data just in one particular controller but in all your queries!
If you really want to stop worrying about SQL injection use PDO.

If you insist on using `mysql_query` - create / use a database class wrapper and use `mysql_real_escape_string` function in all methods performing queries. Something like this:

```
DB::select()->from('table')->where('field1', '=' $param1);
```

where() method will use `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

Comment: I agree, in my (own) framework models(and therefore db-data) can only be accessed from controllers. From this point of view I want to achieve the asked ;)